# ERROR: Failed to get installation proxy (instproxy_client_start_service returned -256)

Tags: ios, iphone, android-studio, proxy

I am trying to run my android project app on iphone, with help of Intel multi OS engine. I get a successful build:

```
Build started (1.0.702)<br>
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.<br>
:ios-moe:copyNatives<br>
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE<br>
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE<br>
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE<br>
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:compileJava UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:processResources UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:classes UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeMainProGuard UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeMainRetrolambda UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeMainDebugDex UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeMainDebugArm64Dex2Oat UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeMainResourcePackager UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeMainStartupProvider UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeMainDebugArm64IphoneosXcodeProvider UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeMainDebugArmDex2Oat UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeMainDebugArmv7IphoneosXcodeProvider UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeXcodeProjectGenerator UP-TO-DATE<br>
:ios-moe:moeMainDebugIphoneosXcodeBuild UP-TO-DATE<br>

BUILD SUCCESSFUL<br>
<br>
Total time: 2.8 secs<br>
BUILD FINISHED<br>
iOS Device: <br>
Launching application: Java/AndroidProjects/Projekt2/ios-moe/build/moe/xcodebuild/sym/Debug-iphoneos/ios-moe.app<br>
```

But then, it throws me next error:

**ERROR: Failed to get installation proxy (instproxy_client_start_service returned -256)**

and application process has been terminated.

I didn't find any information about specific error on internet.

Any solutions?

Comment: I always get the same error, but you could open the iOS project with Xcode and run it from there.